# Run pipeline stages when only the predecessor stage is completed - gitlabci

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I ran into this situation:

I have 3 stages in a gitlab-ci pipeline:

The first stage is intended to trigger and run automatically on change of master branch.

The second stage will run only after manual approval, using `when: manual`.

Now, I want the third stage to run automatically after the second stage is completed.

The only thing I found out that could make sense is `when: on_success`, which is the default value. But I don't get the desired outcome since the third stage run right after the first stage is completed (while the second stage hasn't been manually approved yet).

How can I achieve that condition (stage 3 will be triggered only by stage 2 completion)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior happens because your manual job (the second stage) don't have `allow_failure: false` value

The manual jobs on gitlab ci has `allow_failure: true` as default
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure

If you set the value as `false`, the gitlab ci will not continue until this job finishes with success

Comment: Works! Thank you. I wonder why the default is true then.